# What is the name of the service to be used for push notification?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I read about [push notification in Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I could use this mechanism to receive notifications from a web service: obviously, the web service must be designed to send notifications.

1. Can I use the push notification without knowing the name of the web service, but knowing its IP address and listening port?
2. What types of WCF bindings are supported by Windows Phone 7? I read that I can use only HTTP calls. So can Windows Phone 7 communicate only with `BasicHttpBinding` web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question about push notifications:

Your app will need to know about the web service you wish to receive messages from as you must pass it the channel Id to use to send messages to your app on that device. You don't need to know the "name" of it. You just need a Uri, which could, of course, just be an IP address and port number.